# facebook integration ios 5

Tags: facebook, ios5, xcode4.2, facebook-ios-sdk

I have tried a lot to get facebook integrated to ios 5.0 in my X-code 4.2. I tried facebook sdk 3.0.8(which was the last package sdk that supported ios 5. The problem was that the samples provided in the sdk didnt work since they need a framework "Accounts.framework". I have tried a lot to download it, but it is not possible to get it.I cant find it in my system too. Somebody help me please.

Comment: have you made sure that Social.framework and Accounts.framework are optional in Build Phases